# getaddrinfo with flag AI_NUMERICHOST

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2

Please tell me something I can't understand. There is a function `getaddrinfo()` and there is a flag `AI_NUMERICHOST`. MSDN says that in `getaddrinfo()` with this flag, you need to send the numeric value of the IP address, and not the domain name. But why?

I already have an IP address, why should I ask DNS for an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo()` outputs `sockaddr_...` structs (`sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`) for the requested host/service.  It is not just about IP addresses, it is also about other things, like socket types, service ports, etc, depending on your input and `hint` values.

So, if you already have an IP address **in a string format**, you can have `getaddrinfo()` parse that string for you (specifying `AI_NUMERICHOST` to avoid DNS) into a **binary format** in the output `sockaddr_...`, as well as fill in other `sockaddr_...` fields at the same time.